# On iOS, how do you specify a custom action for a push notification without a category?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We are currently using a push service that does not yet allow for custom categories. With that said, all of our pushes need the same "Reply" action. Is it possible to accomplish this without a `category` property in the `aps` payload of the push notification?

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW26)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A category is required for notifications to have custom actions. The category is what the OS uses to find the custom actions to associate with your notification. Apple documentation states:

> When your push server wants to send a notification to a user, it can
>   add a category key with an appropriate value to the notification’s
>   payload. When iOS sees a push notification with a category key, it
>   looks up the categories that were registered by the app. If iOS finds
>   a match, it displays the corresponding actions with the notification.

Also for local notifications

> In the case of a local notification, you create the notification as
>   usual, then set the category of the actions to be presented, and
>   finally, schedule the notification as usual

```
      UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
      notification.category = @"INVITE_CATEGORY";
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification]
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that; I was hoping that it would default to some `default` category as it does when selecting the notification layout in the WatchKit app storyboard. Thanks!